# select into inside a trigger statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, triggers

i have this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SIGHTING_DESC
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT bird_name
INTO bn
from birds
where bird_id = :new.bird_id;    
    :new.description := 'A bird of the species ' 
                        || bn 
                        || ' was spotted in the ' 
                        || :new.latitude || ','|| :new.longitude 
                        || ' part of the observation area';
END;
/
```

it keeps saying its invalid. Im trying to retrieve bird_name form its corresponding ID, when say for example this is inserted into the sightings table:

```
INSERT INTO sightings (spotter_id, bird_id, latitude,
longitude, sighting_date)
VALUES (2457, 901, -28.0, 152, '09-MAR-2016');
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Can you please share the exact text of the error?

Comment: the `bn` variable is not defined.

Comment: Please browse through some basis plsql tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare the variable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SIGHTING_DESC
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE bn birds.bird_name%type;
BEGIN
SELECT bird_name
INTO bn
from birds
where bird_id = :new.bird_id;    
    :new.description := 'A bird of the species ' 
                        || bn 
                        || ' was spotted in the ' 
                        || :new.latitude || ','|| :new.longitude 
                        || ' part of the observation area';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

good ol 2200
You have to declare dn before you insert into it.